# To find out whether a user opened a page using 'Open in New Tab' or 'Window' or mouse middle button click?

Tags: asp.net

I have an asp.net application developed in 3.5 framework.

The user can use the application only after logging in. There is a menu(html+image) in my application. For security reason, client insist that, the user should not open any of the menu items by 'Open in New Tab' or 'Open in New Window' or by clicking mouse middle button. ie the user has to open the application only in one window. The same user cannot login from two windows. I can handle if the user is logging in from different browsers. But for same browser, I checked with 'Request.UrlReferrer'. But for 'Open in New Tab' or 'Open in New Window', that value was not null.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The client is totally clueless about web application security. You must find a way to convince them that while fulfilling their request might give them a warm feeling, it will do nothing at all for security.

Comment: OutlookWebAccess is able (or was able) to detect that and block the second browser window - I think it is managed by submitting a cookie, which identifies the browser during a long polling operation.